# Script to create new sheets that are protected (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, protected

I already have a script for a button that save and create a new sheet of the saved version.

> The goal is to modify a cashier sheet and to create a copy with the date and the name of the cashier. The only part missing for this script is that everytime a new version of the sheet is created it would be protected.

For example, on the picture, the first sheet is called Auberge and it's the one that we modify. Now, I would like that all the new sheets that we create when we press on the button Save, like the one called Alex 4 août, be protected automatically. Then, only the manager could modify the final versions of the cashiers sheets. The employees would only be able to modify the sheet called Auberge and then save it.

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Have you already made a search/research effort?

Comment: Yes. I've researched it a few hours.

Comment: Great! Please add a brief description of you findings and about where are you stuck.